# Is it advisable to connect a sump pump to pop-up sprinkler heads?

Tags: plumbing, irrigation, sump

My home doesn't offer a great place to eject sump water due to a very level landscape. I'm thinking of adding 3-5 standard pop-up sprinkler heads to the output line. This would allow better distribution of the ejected water than though a single output point.

However, since the system would need to be under pressure, I'd have to disconnect it seasonally and blow out the lines to prevent freeze damage.

Are there any other obvious downsides to this plan?

Comment: Any idea if the pump will provide enough pressure to run the sprinklers?  That would be my first concern.

Comment: I would think so judging by the volume of water being moved. It wouldn't matter much if the spray has a short radius. It's still better than a single dump point on a flat lawn.

Comment: more work and more money, but another angle would be to setup the sump to flow into a rainbarrel with a dedicated sprinkler pump.

Comment: I like this second idea better because the last time you're likely to need the sprinklers to be running is when the sump pump is running

Comment: That's a fair point, except that when the sump is running often the rain barrel would quickly fill, and therefore would need to be emptied at roughly the same time. It wouldn't function as a storage mechanism unless it was huge.

Comment: I don’t think pop up sprinkler will pop up, the spring to retract them is to strong. I think it would be better to use drainage pop ups https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00HCA3SRS/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awdb_t1_kXecBbT7X73E2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ingenious, except I’d worry about: 1) timing, 2) seasonal conflict, 3) head contamination, 4) pressure stress.

1) Timing: Murphy’s Law...but you could locate the heads away from decks, walkways, etc.

2) Seasons: Seems like the sump pump would run most during the “wet” season and not during the “dry” season when the sprinklers need it most. Could you install a valve to allow a regular water source during the dry season? (It will be most difficult during the shoulder seasons.)

3) Head Contamination: I don’t know what the pump is draining, but it would need to be very very clean. Or, you’d need a filtering system...which sounds expensive.

4) Pressure Stress: You’ll need to “size” the system (number of heads) appropriately to match the size of the pump or it could blow the heads into your neighbor’s yard.

Comment: Heh. I did think about timing. We'd learn after a dousing or two. :P My sump water is exceptionally clean. I'll have to investigate what pressure a typical pump provides. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @isherwood My understanding of pumps is that they have an “initial kick-on” rating and a “running” rating. The kick on rating is way more...I think.